# What are the differences between using "to:" and fat-arrow "=>" in Rails routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In the [RailsGuides routing tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code), they give the following example
of how to set up a simple route using the `to` hash argument:

```
get '/patients/:id', to: 'patients#show'
```

But when you generate a new Rails app (using Rails 4.0.3) with the
`rails new` command, the `config/routes.rb` file generated gives the following
example of a simple route, using a hash key/value separator `=>`

```
get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
```

**Are there any differences between these different methods to define a route, or
are they just the same thing?** [The Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-match) literally says this:

```
match 'path' => 'controller#action'
match 'path', to: 'controller#action'
match 'path', 'otherpath', on: :member, via: :get
```

Which is to say, it doesn't really explain anything.

Comment: The difference is not between `to:` and `=>`. It is between `'products/:id'` being the first argument of `get` or a key of the hash argument.

Comment: it is not called `fat-arrow` but `hash-rocket`

Comment: @bjhaid that is helpful to know, but people searching for this question are probably more likely to describe it as "fat arrow", even if that is not the official name for it.

Comment: @Cupcake I think it would be better to use the standard name other than what you think people would use

Comment: 3000% change in benchmark :D

Comment: @BrianWheeler wouldn't that depend on what you were using for your Ruby engine? What if you used something like [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) instead of the standard Ruby interpreter?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**There is no functional difference between using `to` vs `=>` to define a route
in Rails**. Internally, the routing methods actually convert route arguments of
the form

```
<method> '<path>' => '<controller>#<action>'
```

to this form

```
<method> '<path>', to: '<controller>#<action>'
```

### The Source Code

Here is the actual source that does the conversion (from Rails 4.0.4), in the
[`ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Resources` module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1380-L1390). Note that each of
the `get`, `post`, etc. routing methods eventually passes its arguments through
to this `match` method (comments mine):

```
def match(path, *rest)
  # This if-block converts `=>` to `to`.
  if rest.empty? && Hash === path
    options  = path
    # The `find` method will find the first hash key that is a string
    # instead of a symbol, e.g. `'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'` instead
    # of `to: 'welcome#index'`. By parallel assignment, `path` then becomes
    # the value of the key, and `to` is assigned the value
    # (the controller#action).
    path, to = options.find { |name, _value| name.is_a?(String) }
    # The following two lines finish the conversion of `=>` to `to` by adding
    # `to` to the options hash, while removing the
    # `'welcome/index' => 'welcome#index'` key/value pair from it
    options[:to] = to
    options.delete(path)
    paths = [path]
  else
    options = rest.pop || {}
    paths = [path] + rest
  end
  # More Code...
end
```